# Auto Resize Table (Columns)

Tags: html

I am building a website and I use a table as a header. The table has 7 columns. I use some code to automatically resize my website, the resize script works perfect. Everything resizes except the table when it is at a certain size. I think it's because of the cellpadding which is 15 but I want to keep it at 15. This is the table script:

```
<div id="header">
<table width="100%" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="20" style="font-     family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; color:#FFFFFF; background:#FF0101">
<tr>

<td  width="100%" height="70%" align="center" valign="top"><table align="left"   cellpadding="15" cellspacing="0" class="menu">
<tbody><tr><td class="menu" bgcolor="#5B8CFF"   onmouseover"style.backgroundColor='#B30000';" onmouseout="style.backgroundColor=''"><A   HREF="website" STYLE="text-decoration: none; color: white;">Home</a></td>
<td class="menu" onmouseover="style.backgroundColor='#B30000';"   onmouseout="style.backgroundColor=''"><A HREF="website" STYLE="text-decoration: none; color:   white;">Transport</a></td>
<td class="menu" onmouseover="style.backgroundColor='#B30000';" onmouseout="style.backgroundColor=''"><A HREF="website" STYLE="text-decoration: none; color: white;">Distributie</a></td>
<td class="menu" onmouseover="style.backgroundColor='#B30000';" onmouseout="style.backgroundColor=''"><A HREF="website"  STYLE="text-decoration: none; color:  white;"> Historie</a></td>
<td class="menu" onmouseover="style.backgroundColor='#B30000';"   onmouseout="style.backgroundColor=''"><A HREF="website" STYLE="text-decoration: none; color:     white;">Vacatures</a></td>
<td class="menu" onmouseover="style.backgroundColor='#B30000';" onmouseout="style.backgroundColor=''"><a href="website" style="text-decoration: none; color:         white;">Route</a></td>
<td class="menu" onmouseover="style.backgroundColor='#B30000';" onmouseout="style.backgroundColor=''"><A HREF="website" STYLE="text-decoration: none; color:  white;">Contact</a></td> </tr>


</tbody></table></td>

</tr>
</table></div>
```

I hope somebody could help me to let the table automatic resize with the website width and not stuck at a certain width. Thanks a lot.  ( I changed the `href` to website because I want to keep the website I'm making this for private.)

Comment: Suggestion. It is more semantically correct to use an <ul> to create a menu instead of a <table>. Is there some reason why you are using a table?

Comment: Basically,  your table is getting the min allowed values to be displayed at that point. What are you expecting to happen with some specific port size? Are you trying to do a responsive menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to change your structure to something more flexible, also remember use inline styles are not aceptable (if you only use them due to your example I think it is ok, but always use css, even for examples because it is easy to help you):
Example:http://jsfiddle.net/GBTg4/
HTML

```
<div id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Transport</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Distributie</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Historie</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Vacatures</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Route</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#nav ul
{
    width:100%;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

#nav li
{
    display:inline;
    float:left;
    width:14.28571428571429%;
    background-color: blue;
    text-align:center;
}

#nav a
{
    color:#FFF;
    line-height:35px;
    display:inline-block;
    width:100%;
}
#nav a:hover
{
    background-color:#B30000;
}
```